# How to handle dynamic links in firebase hosting?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I used firebase hosting to host my website. Recently I implemented a proof concept website usually operates with index.html & style.js only.

Functionality Info:
A single HTML+JS file used to host entire small scale website. I am able to modify html body content with javascript requests. But the problem is with reload button in browser.  For example If I click about menu button then JS function will get the data for about from backend and shows. Show the url will be `https://some.domain/about`.

Now If I refresh the page,

1. It will go to 404 page by default.
2. I used below redirection in `firebase.json`. But the result is `https://some.domain` instead of `https://some.domain/about` with correct content page like what is showing while pressing about button.

Codes:

1. Changing URL by manually by `history.pushState(null, null,`/about`);`
2. Redirection `firebase.json`

   "redirects": [ {
         "source": "/about",
         "destination": "/",
         "type": 301
    }]

I want to keep dynamic functionality at the same time I want to keep specific url in address bar with content for that specific url.

How can I get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> When a browser attempts to open a specified source URL, it will be given the contents of the file at the destination URL.

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }, {
    // Serves index.html for requests to both "/foo" and "/foo/**"
    // Using "/foo/**" only matches paths like "/foo/xyz", but not "/foo"
    "source": "/foo{,/**}",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }, {
    // Excludes specified pathways from rewrites
    "source": "!/@(js|css)/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: @MountAin in a simple terms, a *rewrite* is a *redirection* that doesn't change the url. Hope this helps.